# UITableView's last row's separator is disappearing/reappearing

Tags: ios, ios7, uitableview

I'm developing for iOS 7, and I've noticed that for non-grouped table views, the last row's bottom separator sometime appears and sometimes disappears. If I select that row, it usually causes it to disappear, but sometimes I get the opposite behavior. Has anyone else come across this issue?

Comment: show code for add separator to cell please

Comment: The tableview's default separator style is used. This issue then occurs regardless if the cell does or doesn't set its separatorInset property.

Comment: Same issue. The workaround is to create your own separators in a custom UITableViewCell.

Comment: this can also appears for topmost cell also.create your own separators in a custom UITableViewCell

Answer (score 0):

Create your own cell separator and add it to your cell

```
 UIImageView *customSeperator=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourOnePixelImg.png"]];

 [customSeperator setFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.frame.size.height-3, cell.frame.size.width, 2)];

 [cell  addSubview:customSeperator];
```